# Understanding last step of a proof of farkas lemma

Tags: linear-algebra

Im working on the proof of Farkas' Lemma given in "Convex Analysis and Nonlinear Optimization" by Borwein/Lewis. I understood the proof right down to the last step.

So there are points $a_{1},\dots ,a_{m},c\in\mathbb{R}^n, a_{0}=-c$ and scalars $0\leq\lambda_{0},\dots,\lambda_{m}\in\mathbb{R}$ which satisfy $\sum_{0}^{m}\lambda_{i}a_{i}=0$. In the current case is also $\lambda_{0}=0$ and $\lambda_{m}>0$, so we have $a_{m}=-\lambda_{m}^{-1}\sum_{1}^{m-1}\lambda_{i}a_{i}$.

In this version of Farkas' Lemma and this part of the proof we must construct scalars $0\leq\mu_{1},\dots,\mu_{m}\in\mathbb{R}$ so that it satifies $\sum_{1}^{m}\mu_{i}a_{i}=c$.

Now the problem. "I" have already shown the existence of scalars $0\leq\mu_{1},\dots,\mu_{m-1}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu_{m}\in\mathbb{R}$ which satisfy the equation  $\mu_{m}a_{m}=c-\sum_{1}^{m-1}\mu_{i}a_{i}$ by induction.

I obviously see that if $\mu_{m}$ is nonnegative we are done. If not I shall substitute $a_{m}$ with the expression for $a_{m}$ in the second paragraph to get a solution.

My idea is to "create" another $a_{m}$ after the substitution because otherwise the sum seems to be "uncomplete".
I have already tried adding "zero" ($+\sum_{1}^{m-1}\lambda_{i}a_{i}-\sum_{1}^{m-1}\lambda_{i}a_{i}$) or extending the equation by $\lambda_{m}$ but without success.

May you give any hints on the calculation that follows after the substitution?
I hope there are no other information needed to obtain a solution.

Comment: This is hard to answer unless one has the book at hand.

Comment: i'm afraid i don't have a link to the complete book but you can use this links to take a look at the proof in the book: [farkas1](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-846349-1575661339.png.html) and [farkas2](https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-1c2381-1575662015.png.html)

Comment: Are you familiar with the Hahn Banach separation theorem?

Comment: Another ask & run.